# mdadm - raid6 has 4 devices working, but doesn't start and can't add new drives

Tags: raid, mdadm

My software raid6 fails to mount. It looks like two drives failed at the same time, since /proc/mdstat only lists four:

```
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
md0 : inactive sde1[8] sdc1[7] sdd1[9] sdb1[5]
      7813424199 blocks super 1.2

unused devices: <none>
```

Similarly `sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0` says 4 devices are active:

```
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Wed Dec  3 16:26:25 2014
        Raid Level : raid6
     Used Dev Size : 1953280064 (1862.79 GiB 2000.16 GB)
      Raid Devices : 6
     Total Devices : 4
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Fri Dec 31 18:17:20 2021
             State : active, FAILED, Not Started
    Active Devices : 4
   Working Devices : 4
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 64K

Consistency Policy : unknown

              Name : prime-mover:0  (local to host prime-mover)
              UUID : 8663f215:81c2e5d5:acb03ac6:4ebdc19c
            Events : 74090

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       -       0        0        0      removed
       -       0        0        1      removed
       -       0        0        2      removed
       -       0        0        3      removed
       -       0        0        4      removed
       -       0        0        5      removed

       -       8       65        0      sync   /dev/sde1
       -       8       49        1      sync   /dev/sdd1
       -       8       33        4      sync   /dev/sdc1
       -       8       17        5      sync   /dev/sdb1
```

Mounting fails:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/md0
mount: /mnt/well: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

but so does trying to add a new drive, which I set up the same way as all the others:

```
$ sudo mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdf1
mdadm: add new device failed for /dev/sdf1 as 6: Invalid argument
```

(From "as 6" I'm guessing it's trying to add it as device 6, rather than replacing the missing devices 2 and 3, for some reason?)

All four of the existing drives look clean but report bad checksums: `sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdb1`, as a representative example, gives

```
[...]
          State : clean
[...]
    Update Time : Fri Dec 31 18:17:20 2021
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : 1935402d - expected 1935402c
         Events : 74090
```

(Same number of events on all four drives, so that's not the problem.)

Here's the relevant bits of `dmesg`:

```
[   33.337211] raid6: avx2x4   gen() 41239 MB/s
[   33.393878] raid6: avx2x4   xor() 14484 MB/s
[   33.450549] raid6: avx2x2   gen() 45821 MB/s
[   33.507210] raid6: avx2x2   xor() 27873 MB/s
[   33.563876] raid6: avx2x1   gen() 40386 MB/s
[   33.620543] raid6: avx2x1   xor() 23907 MB/s
[   33.677210] raid6: sse2x4   gen() 23743 MB/s
[   33.733876] raid6: sse2x4   xor() 11989 MB/s
[   33.790544] raid6: sse2x2   gen() 23125 MB/s
[   33.847209] raid6: sse2x2   xor() 14725 MB/s
[   33.903876] raid6: sse2x1   gen() 18738 MB/s
[   33.960471] raid6: sse2x1   xor() 12188 MB/s
[   33.960471] raid6: using algorithm avx2x2 gen() 45821 MB/s
[   33.960471] raid6: .... xor() 27873 MB/s, rmw enabled
[   33.960472] raid6: using avx2x2 recovery algorithm
[   33.961777] xor: automatically using best checksumming function   avx
[   33.974316] md/raid:md0: device sde1 operational as raid disk 0
[   33.974317] md/raid:md0: device sdc1 operational as raid disk 4
[   33.974317] md/raid:md0: device sdd1 operational as raid disk 1
[   33.974318] md/raid:md0: device sdb1 operational as raid disk 5
[   33.974858] md/raid:md0: raid level 6 active with 4 out of 6 devices, algorithm 2
[   33.974934] md0: invalid bitmap file superblock: bad magic
[   33.974936] md0: failed to create bitmap (-22)
```

What's stopping it from mounting, or from adding the new drive? Is the problem the bad checksums? Is there any way to recover here?

Comment: `dmesg` of assembly? the checksum is weird (mdadm's algorithm is not random" as you'd expect most checksums to be but it has off-by-ones if some change is not reflected in the metadata) but if that was the problem I would expect the array not to appear in /proc/mdstat at all...

Comment: @frostschutz I've added the only relevant bit from dmesg that I could see. Is there something else I should look for?

Comment: @bakkoting I'm having a similar (but not identical) issue with a RAID6 on a Debian system - did you make any progress on this problem?

Comment: @JimMacKenzie Nope. Nuked it and restored from the offsite backup. It was definitely a software issue, since the physical drives are working fine now.

Comment: Thanks!  I was able to figure out my problem - using the flag "-U=no-bitmap" allowed me to assemble the array ignoring the bitmap, and all seems fine since.  I'm not sure, though, if that would have worked for you.